# How to set orientation to portrait mode, regardless the auto-rotate in Android / React Native

Tags: android, react-native, user-interface, react-native-navigation

I want to set `portrait mode` in my react native android application, I tried to

1. set `android:screenOrientation="portrait"` in my Android `Manifest.xml` file,
2. adding orientation programmatically in my activity as `setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);` but none of these is working.

**Note:** I have added `react-native-navigation` in my project

Any inputs to resolve this? Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried the package "react-native-orientation-locker" , It will work on both android and ios.

Comment: https://medium.com/react-native-training/react-native-portrait-device-orientation-9bcdeeac0b03

Answer (score 0):

if you're using react-native-navigation, try this

```
Navigation.setDefaultOptions({
layout: {
    orientation: ["portrait"],
},
});
```

Check the docs [here](https://wix.github.io/react-native-navigation/#/docs/options-migration?id=orien).